# StackOverFlow exception, need a way around infinite loop

Tags: c#, database, stack-overflow

I am making an app for a friend, and need the user to "input" a value, and return it to the MySQL code I have. this way, what displays will change.

My problem is this: When I do "Form1 newForm = new Form1();" (this is called in DB_Application)
I get a stackoverflow error.

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private DBApplication DB_App = new DBApplication();
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.orderID.Text = "";
        this.orderID.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.EnterKey);
        .....
        this.phoneNumber.Text = DB_App.phone_number;
        .....
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

        private void EnterKey(object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
                //converts the "orderID.Text" to an integer value.
            if (!int.TryParse(orderID.Text, out newCurrentID))
                MessageBox.Show("not a number");

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

public class DBApplication : DBInfo
{
    Form1 newForm = new Form1();  // infinite loop
    public DBApplication()
    {
        OrderID();
    }
    private string OrderID ()
    {
     .... //reads the MySQL info, and outputs the value from the database.
    }
}
```

After the User presses "enter" I need the value to go back into "DB_Application" so the MySQL command may receive it, and output a new value.

Comment: Show us the code for the constructor of Form1.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the constructor and looking at the stack trace?

Comment: sorry, two seconds, ill update it.

Comment: Where is `new Form1()` called?

Comment: Is there a `new Form1` in `InitializeComponent()` somewhere?

Comment: You need to add more code... It's not there. Show us where you call `new Form1()` and maybe add the rest of the code to `Initialize`

Comment: InitializeComponent() only contains design form info.
besides whats already included in the code above, the rest is just design info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your comments and by others, the stack overflow is coming from your `DBApplication` instantiating a `Form1`, which in turn instantiates a `DBApplication`, which in turn instantiates a `Form1` and so on.

Rewrite your `DBApplication` to take a `Form1` as part of its constructor rather than instantiating its own, this will avoid the infinite recursion and likely this is want you want since the `DBApplication` will properly reference the open form:

```
public class DBApplication
{
    private Form1 Form;

    public DBApplication(Form1 form)
    {
        this.Form = form;
    }

    ...

}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DBApplication DB_App;

    public Form1()
    {
        DB_App = new DBApplication(this);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ...

}
```

<s>Depending on the rest of your application, you may want to instantiate `DB_App` *after* the call to `InitializeComponent()`.</s> (On second look at your code, it's pretty obvious that the `DB_App` needs to be assigned *before* calling `InitializeComponent()`.)

Also, since we don't know the full design/usage of `DBApplication`, perhaps you need to flip it around where the `DBApplication` instantiates a `Form1`, and the `Form1` has the existing `DBApplication` passed in instead.

There are generally better ways of doing this (say via dependency injection), but this should be a simple way without completely breaking the architecture you have now.

Comment: Hi, I tried this out, and I got a new error.
Inconsistent accessbility: field type 'DBtest.DBApplication' is less accessible than field 'DBtest.Form1.DB_App'

Comment: What accessibility (`public`, `private`, `internal`, etc.) is the `DBApplication` class and `Form1.DB_App` field?

Comment: I think that did something. I had just left the DBApplication to its default, but once I changed it to "public" it started working.
now i just need to make sure it outputs the correct code.

Comment: I think this helped me move forward, ill know in a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed call `new Form1()` from DBApplication the StackOverflow comes from `new DBApplication()` in Form1 (it's an instance variable). How to solve the problem depends on your application logic.

Comment: Yes, and I need a way around that, or an alternative solution for this problem. So that I don't encounter the infinite loop.

Comment: @AlexMoreno: Can you describe in more detail what it is you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, what is DBApplication? What does your form? One way (though possibly not the best) would be to give Form1 as parameter to `new DBApplication(Form1 form)`.

Comment: DBApplication is generally mySQL syntax, and info used to communicate with the site's database.

Comment: I think it's a bug for DBApplication to create a new Form1 anyway. You probably would write to the *existing* Form1. This could be done by providing this Form1 to the new DBApplication. It's not the best practice though, because DBApplication needs to know Form1 which makes it unnecessarily dependent. One better way would be to define some update event in DBApplication that Form1 subscribes to. This is similar to how forms communicate with each other. There are surely references to be found on SO.